# Copy/Paste through tabs on Chrome with iMacros?

Tags: tabs, copy, extract, paste, imacros

```
'part 1 - copy session
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Name EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/a'/g, \"à\") .replace(/e'/g, \"è\") .replace(/i'/g, \"ì\") .replace(/o'/g, \"ò\") .replace(/u'/g, \"ù\") .replace(/A'/g, \"À\") .replace(/E'/g, \"È\") .replace(/I'/g, \"Ì\") .replace(/O'/g, \"Ò\") .replace(/U'/g, \"Ù\")")
SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:EN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Locales_1__Name EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
WAIT SECONDS=2.0

'part 2 - paste session
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:IT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Locales_0__Name CONTENT={{!VAR1}} 
etc
etc
etc
```

This is the first part of code I used until now.
Now I need to copy my source text from another tab of chrome in order to make this one the **{{!VAR1}}** which will be pasted all over the textboxes in another tab.

```
TAB T=1
FRAME F=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:MagicZoomHeader EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/a'/g, \"à\") .replace(/e'/g, \"è\") .replace(/i'/g, \"ì\") .replace(/o'/g, \"ò\") .replace(/u'/g, \"ù\") .replace(/A'/g, \"À\") .replace(/E'/g, \"È\") .replace(/I'/g, \"Ì\") .replace(/O'/g, \"Ò\") .replace(/U'/g, \"Ù\")")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAB T=2
```

This is the code which extract the text I need from TAB 1.
In order to do this, I write the code using TAB T=1 (to copy and create the first VAR) and TAB T=2 in order to paste the text.
When the macro goes to TAB 2 (starting part 2), suddenly stopped working doing a sort of infinite loading before process this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:IT
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-form ATTR=ID:Locales_0__Name CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Why this happens? How can I resolve that?

Comment: Try to add the line `FRAME F=0` immediately after your line `TAB T=2`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!!

Comment: That's possibly a bug. But the issue has been solved and it's nice to hear.